# rails asset_path() not returning digest version anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I finally got my assets working on heroku...but I went to precompile again after I added more assets and now the asset_path helper doesn't return the digest version and everything is broken again. Here's what I have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url("<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3') %>");
```

this would generate the digest version for the application-XXXXX.css file. However, now when I do assets:precompile, this same code (didn't change a thing) returns the non-digest version, which doesn't work.

What did i do wrong here?

EDIT: it also seems the version that the correct digest version of the URL appeared looks way different from the one that didn't come out correctly. one version of the css file spans wide (the correct version) and the other version is very long down the source file. it seems I did something to "process" the original css file the first time but i can't reproduce that.

EDIT2: more info:

```
helper.asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3")
 => "/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3"
```

using the helper.asset_path doesn't return the correct digest url

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once because I placed my images in a sub-directory of the assets folder. Essentially, I had a number of icons I placed in `assets/images/icons/`.

Now whenever I used `asset_path('foo.png')` it would return `foo.png`. The problem was, I needed to prepend the path information, `asset_path('icons/foo.png')`.

I am not sure if this is the same problem you had, but it sounds similar.